# Remote debugging C# application in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging, managed

I try to remote debug C# application (remote PC under WinXP (32bit), VS runs under Win7 (64bit) i got an error message:

`Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging.
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. See help for more information.`

On both machines i set-up user accounts with same name/password, and both machines locates on same work group in LAN.

When I enabled login audit on WinXP I see strange record on event log, common sense of this is: `login forbidden for user SYSTEM`, but i run VS and remote debug moniton by another user name.

Can somebody explain me how to beat this strange error?

Upd: I tryed to run VS2010 as remote user with command:
`runas /user:pc_name\user_name path_to_vs_ide`
then pass password. IDE was started succesfully, but when i choose "Attach to process..." and wrote `pc_name` in qualifier field, i got same error as above:
`Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.`

So my question is still yet actual. How to remotely debug C# applications?

Upd2: **Problem solved after install new pure copy of WinXP.**

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have two computers, C1 and C2.  You create a user Alex on both, and each copy of Alex has the same password.  Same user, right?

These are *not* the same user login.  Each has a different unique identifier (UID).

If you try to log in to C1 from C2 using "Alex" as the user name, the user you are using is the Alex from C2, not the Alex from C1, which is the principal the remote system will use to authenticate.  But the remote system doesn't know who Alex from C2 is.

Try changing your remote credentials to your equivalent of "C1\Alex": the remote computer name, a `\`, and the user name.

Comment: Thank you for answer, @Amy. Can you tell me which actions i will need to do for change credentials?

Comment: Like I said, precede the username with the name of the remote system.

Comment: Where i should do this, i.e. in which field of which program/window?

Answer (score 1):

You can see more info here on how to set up remote tools: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx Gregg's blog is very useful for account requirements: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2008/05/15/visual-studio-remote-debugger-service-user-account-requirements.aspx

You really want two local user accounts, one on host and remote host, with the same username and password (to have Visual Studio authenticate using a local account that matches a remote account (username and password) that has been given permissions to debug in msvsmon.exe)

Windows cached credentials - if you accessed a resource and checked “remember me”, Windows cached credentials to that resource. If you ever attempted to Attach To Process using the current user logged into the local machine, Visual Studio will pick up these cached credentials and attempt to use this as authentication for remote debugging. So you’ll need to clear these credentials (control userpasswords2, Advanced tab, Manage Passwords, Delete the credentials for that remote host)

Now you can either attempt to access the resource (like a share) using a different credential and store it, or you can run Visual Studio as that user you want to debug with that corresponds to the user on the remote side.

Comment: The specified machine credentials were not saved. I deleted all that were saved, but the situation has not changed. Error is still present. May be some other ideas?

Comment: Can you give me a bit more details? Are you using VS2010 on both machines, or one has VS2010 and one the remote debugger for VS 2010?

Comment: VS2010 as IDE on Win7, Remote debugger for VS2010 on WinXP.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, you may need to change the Local Security Policy setting on the Windows XP machine, here are more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek2256kk(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I saw this link before and do all of these recommendation. Tried remote machine as real PC and in VMWare player. But without positive results.